# How do i remove all Bit.ly shortened links from site?

Tags: links

Bit.ly have black listed one site which i linked to which produces a warning.

I have removed this link but want to remove all links which i have shortened using Bit.ly

Is this possible?

Comment: edit, the question is actually kind of difficult to understand. You should re-word it, that's probably why you were downvoted.

Comment: the main question is good but the body is too hard to understand. Sorry, I can't answer this.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by making SQL queries directly in the database. But this only works easily for replacing the URL of a link, not the whole link markup. Replacing all bit.ly links with their original long URL would be the best way to solve the blacklist problem. This is the query you would do, for example in phpMyAdmin or whatever you're using to access your database:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'http://bit.ly/oldlink', 'http://newlink.com/newlink');
```

But if you want to completely remove the link so that only the anchor text remains, there's not much you can do except regex filtering the content with preg_replace:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Remove bit.ly links
Description: Plugin to remove all bit.ly links from post content, keeping the anchor text.
Version: 1.0
Author: Matthias Kretschmann
Author URI: http://mkretschmann.com
*/

// Filter the_content
add_filter('the_content', 'rbl_remove_bitly_links');

// Le function
function rbl_remove_bitly_links($content)
{
    // Regex, FTW!
    // Search & remove link markup for all links
    // with bit.ly, j.mp or bitly.com as href attribute
    return preg_replace('@<a[^<>]*href="(?:http://|https://)(?:bit\.ly|j\.mp|bitly\.com)[^"]*"[^<>]*>@Uis', '', $content);
}
```

This looks for all domains bitly is using, feel free to reduce that to the set you need. You can put this into a new php file in your `wp-content/plugins` folder and activate it. A more lazy way would be to add this to your theme's functions.php file.

Please be aware this won't really remove the links from the database, so they will still be visible in the editor. They just won't appear on the frontend.

Comment: I was thinking about removing them using notepad++. I have a sql dump which i could use to easily remove them but not sure if it would remove the anchor text.

Comment: When i put this file into my child themes functions file my site went white and got a 500 error. I guess it would be best to remove this beforehand: <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Remove bit.ly links
Description: Plugin to remove all bit.ly links from post content, keeping the anchor text.
Version: 1.0
Author: Matthias Kretschmann
Author URI: http://mkretschmann.com
*/

Comment: Be sure to not include "<?php" if you already have an existing functions.php where this is already present. That's why my first recommendation was to use this as a plugin.

Comment: worked fine after i added it to my child themes functions.php and removed <?php

Comment: Brad, great to hear. Although not perfect because the links are still in the database, I think this is the best solution if you don't want to edit the links one by one manually.

Comment: Thanks Matthias and to all involved for your help and support. I have added this forum to my list of the best forums for WordPress. Some of the best technical minds and solutions come from here. Traffic more than doubled as soon as i added this code and removed 500 outgoing links. Cheers